# NoClassDefFoundError when using SimpleGraphQLServlet.Builder

Tags: java, graphql-java

I wrote a simple GraphQL Servlet based on class `SimpleGraphQLServlet`. The constructor of this class is deprecated and it is recommended to use the builder instead. So what I did is to provide my own servlet which forwards the requests to an instance of `SimpleGraphQLServlet` which can be builded in my servlet's `init` method:

```
@WebServlet("/graphql")
public class GraphQLEndpoint extends HttpServlet {

    SimpleGraphQLServlet graphQLServlet;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        graphQLServlet.service(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        graphQLServlet = SimpleGraphQLServlet.builder(buildSchema()).withInstrumentation(new TracingInstrumentation()).build();
    }

    private GraphQLSchema buildSchema() { /* ... */ }
}
```

However, when the `SimpleGraphQLServlet` instance is created, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/instrumentation/NoOpInstrumentation
        at graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet$Builder.<init>(SimpleGraphQLServlet.java:134) ~[graphql-java-servlet-4.7.0.jar:na]
```

which is strange as the class seems to be available in the jar file `graphql-java-8.0.jar`. I declared the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java:8.0"
    compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:4.3.0"
    compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-servlet:4.7.0"

    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"

    testCompile "junit:junit:3.8.1"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1"
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Try removing `compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-servlet:4.7.0"` Since you say it's available in `graphql-java-8.0.jar` you wouldn't need both dependencies declared.

Comment: @dimwittedanimal, thanks for your hint, but only the missing class is in the `graphql-java-8.0.jar` library, but the `SimpleGraphQLServlet` is contained in the `graphql-java-servlet4.7.0.jar` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did receive a hint from @kaqqao who informed me, that my exception is a graphql-java version mismatch. Version 8.0 which I was using is not yet compatible.

Now I use the following graphql-java dependencies, and it works fine:

```
compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java:7.0"
compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:4.3.0"
compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-servlet:4.7.0"
```

@kaqqao closed with the comment "Overriding dependency versions is scary business.". I agree ;-)

Comment: It's absolutely fantastic to see yourself quoted like this :D Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

2020 Answer:

```
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-java-tools:5.6.1'
```

Was missing those dependencies